# Data Structure to store values from lib calls

Tags: c++, design-patterns, data-structures

One lib file is loaded by application many times. Inside the lib files, I do some specific operations(I am storing some data in one map<>). If the lib is loaded many times, I need the data (in the map) to be summarized to one data set from the many times call of lib. I am using C++ in Unix platform for this.
Please help me with which data structure can I use?
I can write data in one file which I can update for different lib calls but I don't want to do that. Please suggest some work around.

Comment: You need a *data store* that can be loaded when the DLL is loaded (initialized).  Something like a file or database.

Comment: Are you use a *shared object* file, *.so*, or a DLL?  I didn't know that DLL files were compatible for Unix.

Comment: Thomas Matthews: I cannot use DB(due to framework constraints) but yes I can use file. But I am trying to find work arounds of not using file. I am using .so here as it is in UNIX

Comment: Possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780461/how-to-share-global-variables-in-a-shared-library-so-across-instances-of-the-s ?