# Singleton class not working as expected C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I am working on a project that involves creating a singleton class.. So I have created a shared library for the singleton class and created two binaries to use this class. When the first exe calls the class's static function "getInstance()" a new instance of Singleton is created and this is expected but when i call getInstance() from the second exe a new instance of Singleton is created again ideally it should have returned the instance created in first case. Here is he code

singelton.h :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class Singleton
{
private:
    static Singleton *single;
    Singleton()
    {
        //private constructor
    }
public:
    static Singleton* getInstance();
    void method();
    ~Singleton()
    {
    }
};
```

singleton.cpp

```
#include "singleton.h"

Singleton* Singleton::single = NULL;
Singleton* Singleton::getInstance()
{
    if(single == NULL)
    {
        printf("Creating a new instance of singleton\n");
        single = new Singleton();
        return single;
    }
    else
    {
        return single;
    }
}

void Singleton::method()
{
    cout << "Method of the singleton class" << endl;
}
```

main_test1.cpp :

```
#include "singleton.h"

int main()
{
    printf("entering test1\n");
    Singleton* singleton = Singleton::getInstance();

    if(singleton != NULL)
    {
        singleton->method();
    }

    while(1)
    {
        sleep(60);
    }
}
```

main_test2.cpp :

```
#include "singleton.h"

int main()
{
    printf("entering test2\n");
    Singleton* singleton = Singleton::getInstance();

    if(singleton != NULL)
    {
        singleton->method();
    }
}
```

Makefile :

```
DEPS = singleton.h
CC = gcc

shared :  $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -o libsingleton.so singleton.cpp -fPIC -shared

test1 : main_test1.o libsingleton.so
    $(CC) -o test1 main_test1.o libsingleton.so -lstdc++ -rdynamic

test2 : main_test2.o libsingleton.so
    $(CC) -o test2 main_test2.o libsingleton.so -lstdc++ -rdynamic

clean : 
    rm *.o test2 test1 libsingleton.so

.PHONY : clean
```

Expected result :

```
$./test1&
$ entering test1
Creating a new instance of singleton
Method of the singleton class

$ ./test2
entering test2
Method of the singleton class
```

Current result :

```
$./test1&
$ entering test1
Creating a new instance of singleton
Method of the singleton class

$ ./test2
entering test2
Creating a new instance of singleton
Method of the singleton class
```

Edit :Since I now know its not possible to do what i wanted to do using a shared library of a singleton class, I now plan to use shared memory approach. I came across some good material on using shared memory(shmget) or mmap  check this link, http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/html/single/bgipc.html .

Comment: Two mains means two separate programs.

Comment: After first process exits the singleton is destroyed. And (what is more important) each process has its own address space and flow control, so each of them will have it's own `Singleton::single` variable and create its own singleton instance.

Comment: Singletons don't work like that. If you want two programs to share an object then you should look at memory mapped files (for instance).

Comment: put a printf in destructor and see what happens.

Comment: @VTT thats the reason why I put a sleep in a while 1 loop in the first exe so that it doesnt get destroyed .

Comment: @AkshayVernekar Your approach cannot work, even though you have a shared library, each application gets it's own copy of the data in that library. You need to look to other techniques such as memory mapped files. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780461/how-to-share-global-variables-in-a-shared-library-so-across-instances-of-the-s

Comment: Singletons are only unique to each running program. Two different programs get two different singletons.

Comment: So my assumption was wrong, I assumed the global scope was across the whole system . It seems like the scope is restricted to an application .

Comment: @P.W: destructor is not called as there is a memleak. and anyway `./test1` doesn't finish with infinite loop.

Comment: I believe you need to learn more about the relationships between hardware, operating system, and applications.